# How to get the original extension name even if we change the extension name using expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

How to get the original file name extension even if i change the extension name of files intensionally. for example one file is for xls format i changed its extension to .pdf so is there any option we can get the original extension of file upload ?

```
let avatar = req.files.avatar;
            
avatar.mv('./uploads/' + avatar.name);
```

Comment: Where is this happening? What is the type of `avatar`? Give some surrounding context, to understand the issue better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you can do is by getting the `MIME` type of the file. If you're using Linux then you could use the `exec` or `execSync` function to run the `file` command:

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
const mimeType = execSync('file --mime-type -b "' + '<file-path>' + '"').toString();
console.log(mimeType.trim());
```

If you input an excel file on the command above, it will read as `text/html` Linux reads like a text/html. For better `MIME` type recognition, you could install [`xdg-mime`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-mime) on your system and replace the command on the function above.

```
const mimeType = execSync('xdg-mime query filetype "' + '<file-path>' + '"').toString();
```